# How to show a message on the lock screen in case I lose the phone?

Tags: lock-screens

I want to show a message on the lock screen in case I lose the handset.

How do I do this?

<sup>If relevant, my device is a [Samsung Galaxy S II](http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxys2/html/).</sup>

Comment: What Android version?

Answer (score 0):

For ICS and later:

- Settings
- Lock screen
- Screen security
- Owner info, here is where a note is entered

This part is a bit confusing as there's no save etc, so just enter something, and back out, *you will not lose what you typed*, keep backing out until back on home screen. Next time screen lock kicks in or press power button to lock it, a note will appear.

*But having said that, if the phone is lost, whoever will pick it up will more than likely ignore it!*